# Azure B2C Single Logout not working in Edge or IE11

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-edge, azure-ad-b2c, single-logout

I have 3 ASP.Net Webforms sites using AAD B2C single sign-on, which is working perfectly fine an all browsers. However, I cannot get single logout to work in Edge or IE11, but logging out of each site individually works OK. When using the likes of Chrome or Firefox it works flawlessly - logout of one site, go to the others and, say, refresh or click a link and I'm then logged out.

The Logout URLs are all set correctly in B2C, otherwise it wouldn't work in any browser. What I have found is that when logging out from Edge and IE11, a request to each of the Logout URLs is never sent, so consequently the code I have on the logout pages to complete the logout and clear all sessions and cookies never fires. I've found nothing online to suggest why this could be happening. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this happen with local accounts? federated accounts? social accounts? all of the above?

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity This is with local accounts.

Comment: due the complexity of the issue please [open a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-troubleshooting-support-howto#open-a-support-ticket). They will guide you and most possible ask and analyze a fiddler trace. Once you do that please come back and share your support ticket case via a private message so we can keep track of it.